# remove node in a tree does not maintain its level

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-ui

in my tree that i am making with the help of jquery, if i remove the parent node i want its immediate children to become the parent.

But if the immediate children have sibling/siblings at same level than all the sibling should become a root node .i think it would be more clear with my example.

- a

  - b

    - c
  - d
  - e

consider this as my tree 
what i want is if i remove a than b,d,e should become individual root node
and c should come under b.

i am pasting my code it does achieve the root node thing but 
it make c as the same level of b.

```
       var liFirst = $(spnElement).parents('li:first');
        $(childPrsnt).insertBefore(liFirst);

        $(spnElement).parents('li:first').remove();
        $(childPrsnt).find('li').unwrap('ul:first');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want immediate children (not *all* descendants), so instead of [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) use [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) here, like this:

```
var liFirst = $(spnElement).parents('li:first');
$(childPrsnt).insertBefore(liFirst);

$(spnElement).closest('li').remove();
$(childPrsnt).children('li').unwrap();
```

Also note the use of [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) with [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), it's just a cheaper/shorter way to get the same element.